# How do I get a UIButton to change its color by clicking it?

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I want to make an app for iphone. It is a Nonogram something similar to this: http://www.puzzle-nonograms.com/ How can I make the UIButtons changes their color from white to black and reverse?

Answer (score 5):

.h file

```
UIButton *button;
BOOL clicked;
```

.m file
    - (void)viewDidLoad

```
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    clicked=YES;
    button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(changeBtnColor)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [button setTitle:@" 1 " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(void)changeBtnColor{
    if (clicked) {
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        clicked=NO;
    }
    else{
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        clicked=YES;

    }



}
```

I hope it will help. Best of luck..

Answer (score 1):

No need to ivar a boolean, buttons have selected, highlighted and normal states built into them.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Normal State" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:@"Selected State" forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"normal_image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_image"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.view addSubview:button];

}

-(void)buttonPress:(UIButton *)button{
    button.selected = !button.selected;
    //do your other code here for button selection
}
```

Otherwise set up the button states inside interface builder and just have the buttonPress selector handle the state change.